# Selecting the right MCU for a FreeRTOS embedded system

Tags: memory, microcontroller, rtos, stm32, freertos

I got a project going on where i am going to interface STM32 MCU with a bunch of sensors (Accelerometer, gyroscope etc..) make some math on the downloaded sensor data, and generate an appropiate output to 6 PWM's. Along with this I'll have an active wireless communication module, and maybe a little LCD screen (nothing fancy). Plus some minor addintional functionality.

I am planning to use FreeRTOS for controlling the system, but i can't decide if it's a overkill? should I just use a small co-operative scheduler instead?

I've got an FreeRTOS system up and running on my STM32F100RB with 8kB RAM and 128kB Flash, but I can't decide if that is even enough memory for a system running FreeRTOS?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MCU is enough for your memory requirements.

In  my opinion if you have not budget problems for mcu-selection, you could choose a mcu from a higher STM32 series like STM32F1xx or STM32F2xx. Thus, the ram size could be larger than 32K.